# Find out day with highest sales and lowest sales in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small restaurant POS system that logs all the sales in a table named 'orders'.

```
sale_id - item - date - time - quantity - price
```

I want to find out the day that had the lowest sales and also the highest sales (item_id * quantity) and on what days they occurred (date) over the past 7 days.

```
$past_1day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday'));
$past_2day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday -1 day'));
$past_3day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday -2 day'));
$past_4day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday -3 day'));
$past_5day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday -4 day'));
$past_6day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday -5 day'));
$past_7day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday -6 day'));
$highestSales = array();

$get_past1day = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(quantity) AS sales_qty FROM orders WHERE item = '$item' AND date = '$past_1day'") or die(mysql_error());
$past1day = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_past1day);
array_push($highestSales, $past_1day,$past1day['sales_qty']);

$get_past2day = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(quantity) AS sales_qty FROM orders WHERE item = '$item' AND date = '$past_2day'") or die(mysql_error());
$past2day = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_past2day);
array_push($highestSales, $past_2day,$past2day['sales_qty']);

$get_past3day = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(quantity) AS sales_qty FROM orders WHERE item = '$item' AND date = '$past_3day'") or die(mysql_error());
$past3day = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_past3day);
array_push($highestSales, $past_3day,$past3day['sales_qty']);

$get_past4day = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(quantity) AS sales_qty FROM orders WHERE item = '$item' AND date = '$past_4day'") or die(mysql_error());
$past4day = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_past4day);
array_push($highestSales, $past_4day,$past4day['sales_qty']);

$get_past5day = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(quantity) AS sales_qty FROM orders WHERE item = '$item' AND date = '$past_5day'") or die(mysql_error());
$past5day = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_past5day);
array_push($highestSales, $past_5day,$past5day['sales_qty']);

$get_past6day = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(quantity) AS sales_qty FROM orders WHERE item = '$item' AND date = '$past_6day'") or die(mysql_error());
$past6day = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_past6day);
array_push($highestSales, $past_6day,$past6day['sales_qty']);

$get_past7day = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(quantity) AS sales_qty FROM orders WHERE item = '$item' AND date = '$past_7day'") or die(mysql_error());
$past7day = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_past7day);
array_push($highestSales, $past_7day,$past7day['sales_qty']);

echo max($highestSales);
```

However this is not giving me the correct result and I'm sure it's not the most elegant method. I'd appreciate any pointers to simplify my code and also access the day with the highest and lowest sales.

Thanks,

DB

Comment: do you save in that table the orders(one order per one row) ? if so, how do you save the orders with many items?

Comment: Good question, I actually tried to have another column called 'order_group' which is linked to another table. As this wasn't so relevant for the question though I left it out to try and make things simpler.

Comment: I need to know what is inside that table so I can write the correct query. do you have *one sale with one item per one row* ? , If you provided some records from the table that will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to help. Some sample data would be:

Comment: sale_id - item - date - time - quantity - price

Comment: '1' - '12' - '2017-03-20' - '16:49' - '2' - '3'

Comment: ''2' - '12' - '2017-03-20' - '17:35' - '1' - '3'

Comment: '3' - '12' - '2017-03-21' - '12:054 - '1' - '3'

Comment: I want to find the info on what day had the highest sales so from that sample data in the past 7 days. I'd be looking to find that '2017-03-20' had the highest number of sales of item '12' of 3 and also the lowest sales from that of item '12' where 1 on '2017-03-21'. I really appreciate your help. @Accountant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the day that has the highest sales in the past 7 days:

```
SELECT date, sum(quantity) total_day_quantity

from orders  
WHERE  date >= '$past_7day'
GROUP by date
ORDER BY total_day_quantity desc
LIMIT 1;
```

For the lowest :

```
SELECT date, sum(quantity) total_day_quantity

from orders  
WHERE  date >= '$past_7day'
GROUP by date
ORDER BY total_day_quantity asc
LIMIT 1;
# for sales by values not quantities sum(quantity * price)
```

*Note: your schema assumes that you have one item per one order which is not realistic in life examples.*

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: You could add the following code to the SQL query `SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,  DATEADD(day, -7, @date), GETDATE())` and streamline your code where all the work is done by the sql server and not the browser.

Comment: @Addohm You are right about letting the sql server do as much of the work, but I was trying to stick to the op code. Thank you for the idea